# How to send WebSocket data from View to Controller and reworked data send to View with Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I'm trying send websocket data from view to controller and again reworked data send to view in for example table with button or something like this.
Now sending data to controller works:

### View:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webSocket;
    var webSocketValue;
    function webSocketResults() {
        webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://......");
        webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            webSocketValue = event.data;
            $("#webSocketValue").text(webSocketValue);
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("getWebSocketResults", "Home")",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: webSocketValue
            });
        };
        showCurrenciesData(webSocketValue);
    }
    function showCurrenciesData() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("getWebSocketResults", "Home")",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Sukcess!!" + result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve data.');
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = webSocketResults;
```

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult getWebSocketResults(Currencies currencies)
    { //do something with data "currencies" and dynamicly send this to view
        var webSocketItems = currencies.items.ToList();
        return Json(webSocketItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In Controller i have data (Object) from View.
How to send this data dynamically. New data from WebSocket arrives every minute.
Sending data to view does'nt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you called two times. first times did not handle result. second times no have paremeter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var webSocket;
var webSocketValue;
function webSocketResults() {
    webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://......");
    webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
       showCurrenciesData(event.data);
    };

}
function showCurrenciesData(data) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("getWebSocketResults", "Home")",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Sukcess!!" + result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve data.');
        }
    });
}
window.onload = webSocketResults;
```

Comment: Now in controller is no data, just null.

Comment: can follow xmlhttp requests on browser network debugger